# Get each td width of a table and set it to another table td width using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi all am trying to set td width on a table by getting width value of another table's td each cells have different widths need to get each width and set it to this parallel tables td's because both td has to looks same in width. how can is get each width and set to another table td in a row

Example table my code is like the same with more rows in second table

```
table td {
 min-width:54px;
}
<table id="table1">

<tr id="trBindRampRateList">
   <td>
      Ab
   </td>
   <td>
      Abcsddddddd
   </td>
   <td>
      Abcsdddddddssss
   </td>
<tr>

</table>
<table id="table2">

    <tr id="tblCategoriesScoresList">
       <td>
          <input type="text"/>           
        </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text"/>           
        </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text"/>           
        </td>
    <tr>

    </table>



  var mWid; 
    $('#trBindRampRateList td').each(function() { mWid = $(this).width(); }); 

$('#tblCategoriesScoresList  td').each(function() { $(this).css("min-width","mWid"+"px") });
```

I want to stretch the table 2's td width as per table td width both has to set same

Comment: did you try $('#trBindRampRateList').children('td').each... instead?

Answer (score 1):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nzjw5pto/):** ***Check in console . The widhts are setting right***

There are lots of corrections in your code .

> `$(this).css("min-width","mWid"+"px")` **mWid** is a variable , putting it in quotes won't work.

Try this :-

```
var arrOfTable1=[],
    i=0;

$('#table1 td').each(function() {
 mWid = $(this).width(); 
 arrOfTable1.push(mWid);
});

$('#table2 td').each(function() {
 $(this).css("min-width",arrOfTable1[i]+"px");
 i++; 
});
```

Hope it work !

Comment: The min-width settings affect the 2nd table, but the actual width when inspected does not match what we set as min-width for a table-element.  How old is HTML, and width/min-width on td/th elements is still broken?

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = $("table#first tr:first-child > td").length;
var width = (100 / num) + "%";
$("#first td").css("width", width);
$("#table2 td").css("width", width);
```

Comment: All the td size will be equal of both the table tag

Comment: you can add the html part?